# Controller conflicting with nonexistent controller in azure mobile app

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I am getting an error when attempting to use a table controller.

Debugging the controller remotely shows this message

```
The request for 'appCenter' has found the following matching controllers:
AppName.Backend.Controllers.AppCenterController
AppNameService.Controllers.AppCenterController
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector.SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpControllerSelectorTracer.<>c__DisplayClass3.<System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.IHttpControllerSelector.SelectController>b__1()
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.TraceBeginEnd(ITraceWriter traceWriter, HttpRequestMessage request, String category, TraceLevel level, String operatorName, String operationName, Action`1 beginTrace, Action execute, Action`1 endTrace, Action`1 errorTrace)
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Will use same 'XmlMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation=XmlMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Selected formatter='XmlMediaTypeFormatter', content-type='application/xml; charset=utf-8'', Operation=DefaultContentNegotiator.Negotiate
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Response, Status=500 (InternalServerError), Method=GET, Url=https://appname.azurewebsites.net/tables/appcenter?ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0, Message='Content-type='application/xml; charset=utf-8', content-length=unknown'
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync
```

My problem is there is no AppName.Backend.Controllers.AppCenterController.

I had a project with that name in mysolution however I rolled back using git. I also deleted the AppName.Backend service from azure. Why would this message still be showing.

Steps already taken:
Rebuilt all projects in solution.
Deleted obj and bin folders and rebuilt.
Rolled back using git and deleted new folders

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it seems that you have did some trials about this issue. I assumed that you could follow the steps below to isolate this issue:

- Please try to launch your project on your local side to see whether it could work as expected;
- Create a new Web App and deploy your mobile project to see whether this issue belongs to the old Azure Mobile App;
- Please try to check whether `AppName.Backend` project or `AppName.Backend.dll` still left in your Git repository;
- Check your deployed mobile app content via [Kudu console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) to find whether `AppName.Backend` is still survived.

Comment: It was working locally. There is no mention of AppName.Backened anywhere in my git repo.

Comment: I think I managed to fix it when I changed a publish setting to remove all files from the server before uploading.

Comment: Are you meaning that you could leverage “Remove additional files at destination” when publishing your app to azure, which could fix this issue? Since some projects have been removed after you have deployed them to Azure, you also could clear “D:\home\site\wwwroot” via KUDU. If my suggestions could help you, please try to mark it as an answer. Or you could post an answer with your detailed steps to fix this issue for other communities who could encounter the similar issue.